# How do I fix Parser Error Message: Could not load type?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ftp

I am trying to create aspx files directly into my website using FTP. My code works fine when uploading pictures or other medias but when I create a file and add the aspx file extension and upload it, I get the following parser error message:

[Parser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LYwQ.jpg)

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: have you tried publishing it first? that will allow everything to be compile in what exactly you need to upload

Comment: Yes I've published it and tried doing it that way as well but I get the same error unfortunately

Comment: did you upload the dlls in the bin?

Comment: Could you develop more on that please? I don't think I've uploaded any dlls. I used the built-in visual studio 2019 FTP publish functionality

Comment: list out what you have published into an empty directory - there should be a `bin` with the types

Comment: Ok I do see the bin directory with the types, so you're suggesting trying to update the dlls of that bin directory as well whenever I upload a aspx file via FTP? Am I understanding this the right way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution, it might not be the best one but all I had to do was get rid of the inherits="Heimwinz[...]" part and it worked just fine.